# Make a UDF independent of DATEFIRST setting

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions

With the help of answers on SO, I have created a SQL Server UDF (below) which returns the next working day (weekday), given a date and a number of days to add.

For example, if the date is a Friday and you wnat to add one day, the return value is that of the following Monday.

This relies on assuming that `@@DATEFIRST` is set to 1 (Monday), because we can't explicitly set `DATEFIRST` in a UDF.

My problem is that I'd like to deploy this function on several servers but they have different `@@DATEFIRST` settings and for maintenance purposes between Production, Test and Dev servers I'd rather just have one function that worked without having to worry which `@@DATEFIRST` setting is in use. I've already spent too long wondering why I was getting different results in different environments!

If the answer is simply "use a Stored Proc" then fair enough.
But if anyone can suggest how to refactor the following to be independent of the `DATEFIRST` setting then that would be great. The significant line is probably going to be `if DatePart(dw, @toDate) not in (6, 7)...`

Function definition:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_AddBusinessDays]
(   
@fromDate       datetime,
@daysToAdd      int
)
RETURNS datetime
AS
BEGIN   
DECLARE @toDate datetime
DECLARE @daysAdded integer

-- add the days, ignoring weekends (i.e. add working days)
set @daysAdded = 1
set @toDate = @fromDate

while @daysAdded <= @daysToAdd
begin
    -- add a day to the to date
    set @toDate = DateAdd(day, 1, @toDate)
    -- only move on a day if we've hit a week day
    if DatePart(dw, @toDate) not in (6, 7)
    begin
        set @daysAdded = @daysAdded + 1
    end
end

RETURN @toDate

END
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`IF (@@DATEFIRST + DATEPART(DW,  @toDate)) % 7  not in (0,1)` should work for all possible `DATEFIRST` values I think.

I'd probably use an Auxilliary Calendar table for this anyway rather than a looping UDF.

Comment: The value returned by DATEPART is dependent upon the current setting of SET DATEFIRST.  Change the one, you change the other.

Comment: @Philip. Agreed. Which is why `@@DATEFIRST` gets added.

Comment: Perfect, that works brilliantly. Re. the Calendar lookup solution, we use this to account for public holidays, non-standard company holidays etc. and combine it with the generic weekdays function where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the names of the week days (which are not be affected by `@@datefirst`):

```
if left(datename(weekday, @toDate), 3) in ('Sat', 'Sun')
 ...
```

As a caveat as martin well points out;

```
SET LANGUAGE Italian
select datename(weekday, GETDATE())

>> giovedì
```

Comment: But I think they are language dependant aren't they?

Comment: Sorry I actually have read the question now and see where you are coming from on this! Hopefully the environments at least all have the same language.

Comment: I like this approach and this is probably my best bet - LANGUAGE varies less than DATEFIRST does, at least. But it is still a potential 'gotcha' when my goal is to use this function on any server without having to tailor it to the environment. Plus, I can't use `SET LANGUAGE` in a UDF in the same way that `SET DATEFIRST` is forbidden.